# Why is torch.randn not been reproducible with all seeding?

Tags: python, random, torch, random-seed

Title says it all, here is my issue:

I want `torch.randn(1)` to be reproducible.

I am using:
CUDA: 12.1
TCC/WDDM
VS Code Jupyter
and have tried the following to `seed` it.

```py
seed=42
torch.manual_seed(seed=seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed=seed)
np.random.seed(seed=seed)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False 

torch.randn(1)
```

I first tried `torch.manual_seed(seed=seed)` alone but was not reproducible.

I was expecting a constant value as an output.

Comment: `torch.manual_seed(seed=seed)` is enough for reproducibility on my system. Is this maybe a hardware specific bug?

Comment: Well, I just tried your comment alone in a separate machine and it still is not reproducible.

Comment: Is it a operating system specific bug? I ran my test on Linux.

Comment: Yeah, I believe so. I cleared all cache and restarted my device and I was able to reproduce it with my seed.